# What does '/' as in 'umask(mask, /)' mean in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

In reading Python document files, I keep encountering help text like

```py
os.umask(mask, /)
```

or

```py
nt.is_dir(self, /, *, follow_symlinks=True)
```

I can't find the meaning of this syntax in any of the Python references.  What does this symbolism mean?

Comment: It might help to provide a link to the document(s) you are referring to.

Answer (score 3):

This is the new [positional-only parameter syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#positional-only-parameters) introduced in Python 3.8.

No argument before the `/` character may be used as a keyword argument.

Using one of your examples:

> `os.umask(mask, /)`

You cannot call `os.umask(mask=SOME_MASK)` but you can call `os.umask(SOME_MASK)`.

Answer (score -2):

OS module in Python provides functions for interacting with the operating system. OS comes under Python’s standard utility modules. This module provides a portable way of using operating system dependent functionality.

`os.umask()` method in Python is used to set the current numeric umask value and get the previous umask value.

umask stands for user file-creation mode mask. This is used use to determine the file permission for newly created files or directories.

Comment: This is informative, but totally unrelated to the OP's question.